# Hilt Generating Activity code that overrides onCreate() and onDestroy()

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

Upgrading Hilt version from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0. We have a custom Activity that we inherit from that is final, but Hilt generates code that overrides these methods and compiling doesn't work. Don't see changes to this in the Hilt commit history, but wondering if something has changed that I don't see.

Error message:

> error: onDestroy() in Hilt_MainActivity cannot override onDestroy() in AppCompatCustomActivity
> public final void onDestroy() {
> ^
> overridden method is final
> 2 errors

Generated Code:

```
  @CallSuper
  @Override
  public final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initSavedStateHandleHolder();
  }

  @Override
  public final void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (savedStateHandleHolder != null) {
      savedStateHandleHolder.clear();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I thought this had always been the case.  The reason being they can manage injectable resources more efficiently.

Comment: Actually found the commit where it was added in 2.49 - 
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/4202

https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.49
https://github.com/google/dagger/commit/1cac33b1d2f9061c8dfea899662dbcdc1f727f24

Comment: Ended up just removing final from our base Activity classes.